# MySQL - Referencing outer table value from double nested subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The query I really need to execute is follows:

```
SELECT      u.points
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM checkin c INNER JOIN wineries w ON w.id = c.winery_id WHERE c.user_id = u.id GROUP BY region_id) b) as states_visited
FROM        users u
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY points DESC
```

However, this causes the following error:

Unknown column 'u.id' in 'where clause'

I've tried with user-defined variables, no errors, but it's not actually referencing the user-defined variable value for some reason:

```
SELECT      @uid := u.id, u.points
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM checkin c INNER JOIN wineries w ON w.id = c.winery_id WHERE c.user_id = @uid GROUP BY region_id) b) as states_visited
FROM        users u
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Any thoughts how I can make this work?   Without the obvious resorting to doing two separate queries?

Comment: Can you simply explain the tables in use, their schema, and what you are actually trying to get in your query result?

Comment: can you set up some test data on sqlFiddle.com and explain what results you're expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the double nesting? And if the `id` is the primary key of table `user`, you don't need the `GROUP BY` either:

```
SELECT      u.points,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM reviews WHERE user_id = u.id) AS review_count
FROM        users AS u
-- GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY points DESC ;
```

You could also `GROUP BY` in a derived table - and then join:

```
SELECT      u.points,
            COALESCE(r.review_count,0) AS review_count
FROM        users AS u
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS review_count
         FROM reviews
         GROUP BY user_id
        ) AS r
        ON  r.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY points DESC ;
```

or join and then `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT      u.points,
            COUNT(r.user_id) AS review_count
FROM        users AS u
    LEFT JOIN
            reviews AS r
        ON  r.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.points
ORDER BY points DESC ;
```

---

The edited version is harder but can be done without double nesting, too:

```
SELECT      u.points,
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT region_id) 
         FROM checkin c INNER JOIN wineries w ON w.id = c.winery_id 
         WHERE c.user_id = u.id 
        ) AS states_visited
FROM        users u
ORDER BY points DESC ;
```

Comment: Apologies, I tried to simplify my query before posting, but I took the hard part out of it!  Please see the revised subquery, which itself has a join that creates multiple rows.

Comment: OK, it is harder, indeed. Remove the double nesting and the internal `GROUP BY` and use `COUNT(DISTINCT region_id)`

Comment: You sir, are a genious!  I love solutions that actually reduce the complexity of the query.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can do what you want with a simpe table join

```
SELECT u.id AS `id`, u.points AS `points`, COUNT(r.review_id) AS `review_count` /* or whatever the id record for reviews table is */
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN reviews AS r
  ON u.id = r.user_id
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `points` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry, I had to make an edit, see comment in ypercube's reply.

Comment: @PhilL I still don;t understand why you would need a subselect at all. Maybe it would help if, in your question, you describe your tables and what exactly you are trying to get in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, users.points, count(*)
FROM users, reviews
WHERE users.id = reviews.user_id
GROUP BY id,points
ORDER BY points DESC
```

[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a41d/2/0)